# Who used to present the Indian Order of Merit?

Tags: india, british-empire

I was reading about the [*Indian Order of Merit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Order_of_Merit), and the *Battle of Saragarhi* in particular. All of the martyred soldiers were, for instance, conferred with the highest gallantry award for natives of British Indian army i.e. the Indian Order of Merit. I could not find information on who presented the medal.

My question, is not specifically about the 21 Sikhs killed at the *Battle of Saragarhi*, but who used to present the Indian Order of Merit medal?

Was it the British monarch or the Governor-General of India (or Viceroy after 1858) ?

Comment: Since the [award](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Order_of_Merit) was introduced under the [Honourable East India Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_India_Company) in 1837, and taken over by the Crown in 1858, it would have been presented under the authority of the Governor-General of India, acting in the name of the British monarch after 1858.

Comment: And the Viceroy of India after the Governor-Generalship became defunct.

Comment: @gktscrk The 'correct' designation for the 'Viceroy of India' was actually '*Governor-General of India*'. Despite its popular usage, the term "*Viceroy*" was a purely ceremonial one without statutory authority. See my answer below and the Wikipedia article on the [List of governors-general of India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_governors-general_of_India) for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

The [Indian Order of Merit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Order_of_Merit) was introduced under the [Honourable East India Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_India_Company) in 1837.  It would therefore have been presented under the authority of the [Governor-General of India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Governor-General_of_India) until 1858 when the territories and assets of the East India Company came under the direct control of the British Crown following the [1857 Indian Rebellion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Rebellion_of_1857).

The Act of Parliament that transferred the territories and assets of the East India Company to the direct control of the British Crown was the [Government of India Act 1858](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_of_India_Act_1858). The Act vested the power to appoint the Governor-General in the sovereign.  The roles and responsibilities remained largely unchanged, so the award would have continued to be presented under the authority of the Governor-General who would then have been  acting in the name of the British monarch.

---

Note that from 1858, the Governor-General was commonly styled the *Viceroy and Governor-General of India*, or simply the *Viceroy of India*. However, the 1858 Governor of India Act did not use the term '*Viceroy*', and neither did the Warrants that appointed later Governors-General.  For example, the [London Gazette of 29 August 1947](https://www.thegazette.co.uk/London/issue/38059/page/4095) records that:

> The KING has been pleased to appoint Rear Admiral the Rt. Hon. the Viscount Mountbatten of Burma, K.G., G.C.S.I, G.C.I.E., G.C.V.O., K.C.B., D.S.O., to be Governor-General of India.

As you can see, despite being popularly known as "*The Last Viceroy of India*", there is actually no mention of '*Viceroy*' in his official title.